# Comparator interface used to compare doubles

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion, compare

I'm using Comparator Interface to compare custom objects to sort ArrayList's. This works fine with int and String values, but when I want to sort/compare doubles I run into troubles.

I know that Java rounds the double in my method and reads 1.7, 1.62, 1.66 as 1, which is the error.

But I cant seem to find a way to overcome this. Here are my methods and result - the result show that the Comparator does not sort the list correctly due to the convertion of double to int.

Note that my "odds" variable is value double and have to be converted to function in Comparator Interface:

```
public Integer getOddsInt() {
        return (int) odds;
    }


public class SortOdds implements Comparator <History>{
    
     public int compare(History a, History b) 
        
        { 
            return a.getOddsInt() - b.getOddsInt(); 
        }
}
```

Result:

```
[ 
  2.62 |  
, 1.7  |  
, 1.62 | 
, 1.66 | 
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be a bit confused - if you want to sort 1.4 before 1.6, but your only possible view of this data is as just '1', what you want is obviously impossible.

But you're the boss of your own code. As the doctor said when the woman asked: "Doctor, it hurts when I wallop myself in the face with a hammer": "Well, stop doing that then!".

Make a method that returns the odds as an actual double. Alternatively, if the SortOdds class is inside the History class, you can directly access the field, which I assume looks something like `private final double odds;`.

compare demands you return an int, but your approach of - is a common trope that is wrong. Don't write your compare runs that way, they don't work for extreme values.

You can't really get away from:

```
if (a.getOdds() < b.getOdds()) return -1;
if (a.getOdds() > b.getOdds()) return +1;
return 0;
```

but fortunately, the method `Double.compare(a, b)` does precisely that. So...:

`return Double.compare(a.odds, b.odds);`

is all you need.

NB: You can make this stuff a ton easier these days:

```
public class History {
    public static final Comparator<History> ODDS_BASED_COMPARATOR =
      Comparator.comparingDouble(History::getOdds);

    private final double odds;

    public double getOdds() { return odds; }
}

// and to use, for example:

List<History> list = new ArrayList<History>();
// add some history objects to it here
list.sort(History.ODDS_BASED_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: Thank you for a very helpfull answer. I'm still new to Java, and this is the first time I work with Comparater. You answer solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

If that is causing trouble, don't do the conversion at all. Just use if-else logic

```
if (a.getDouble() < b.getDouble) {
  return -1 ;
else if (a.getDouble() > b.getDouble){
  return 1 ;
} else {
  return 0 ;
}
```

}

Comment: 'getDouble()' would be a very bad name for the 'getOdds()' method. Also, You're reinventing the wheel; Double.compare(a.getOdds(), b.getOdds()) would do the job, is less error prone, shorter, more idiomatic.

Comment: It was just quick coding, not trying to make Clean Code in my answer :-P (now i see that i don't even get the parenthesis in many places)